# Program not pinging generated IPS just running through them

Tags: ruby, ping

I have a program that generates random IP addresses and attempts to ping them and add ports to them, I will be using this tool for pen testing. I've got it working at one point ,and decided that in order to find which ping method would be used, the program would first discover what OS the user is running and determine the ping method that way; with this:

```
def self.windows?
  return File.exist? "c:/WINDOWS" if RUBY_PLATFORM == 'java'
  RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mingw32/ || RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin32/
end

def self.linux?
  return File.exist? "/usr" if RUBY_PLATFORM == 'java'
  RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /linux/
end

def self.os
  return :linux if self.linux?
  return :windows if self.windows?
  nil
end

def check_os
  if windows?
    @ping = `ping -n 1 #{@ip}`
    check_file
  elsif linux?
    @ping = `ping -c 1 #{@ip}`
    check_file
  else
    @ping = `ping -c 1 #{@ip}`
    check_file
  end
end
```

Now this does figure out the correct OS (I'm sure there's a better way to do this, and if you know of one let me know) but what I'm concerned about is that it doesn't actually use the `@ping` command when prompted for it while doing a full run on the program. Instead what it does is just continuously loop and not ping the IP addresses. (It's suppose to loop until around 3500 IP's are found)

Source code:

```
require 'colored'
require 'timeout'

def self.windows?
  return File.exist? "c:/WINDOWS" if RUBY_PLATFORM == 'java'
  RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mingw32/ || RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /mswin32/
end

def self.linux?
  return File.exist? "/usr" if RUBY_PLATFORM == 'java'
  RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /linux/
end

def self.os
  return :linux if self.linux?
  return :windows if self.windows?
  nil
end

def check_os
  if windows?
    @ping = `ping -n 1 #{@ip}`
    check_file
  elsif linux?
    @ping = `ping -c 1 #{@ip}`
    check_file
  else
    @ping = `ping -c 1 #{@ip}`
    check_file
  end
end

def check_file
  if File.exist?("proxies.txt")
    File.truncate("proxies.txt", 0)
    puts "\n[NOTICE]File exists in system, resuming process.\n".blue.bold
    create_possibles
  else 
    puts "\n[NOTICE]File proxies.txt created successfully.\n".blue.bold
    File.new("proxies.txt")
    create_possibles
  end
end

def create_possibles
  puts "\n[NOTICE]Attempting to ping generated IP addresses.\n".blue.bold


  ports = %w(80 443 1935 2222 3128 3130 7808 8080 8081 8085 8089 
             8090 8102 8104 8106 8118 8119 8123 8888 8898 9000 
             9090 9797 9999 10000 10052 10053 10059 10088 12345 
             18000 18001 18008 37564 40080 55336 59998
            )
  100.times do
    @ip = Array.new(4){rand(256)}.join('.')
    begin
      Timeout::timeout(5) do 
        @ping
        if @ping =~ /Received = 1/ 
          puts "[SUCCESS]Possible proxies created for IP: #{@ip}".green.bold
          File.open("proxies.txt", "a+") do |proxy|
            ports.each { |port| proxy.puts("#{@ip}:#{port}") }
          end
        else
          puts "[ERROR]IP failed to ping: #{@ip}".red.bold
        end
      end
    rescue Timeout::Error, Errno::ENOBUFS
      puts "[WARNING]IP timed out: #{IP}".yellow.bold
      next
    end
  end
  check_for_amount_of_proxies
end

def check_for_amount_of_proxies
  if File.size("proxies.txt") >= 71769
    puts "\n[NOTICE]Proxies created, attempting connection\n".blue.bold
    system("proxies-scanner -f proxies.txt")
    print "[NOTICE]Truncating file: proxies.txt".blue.bold
  else
    puts "\n[NOTICE]File doesn't contain enough proxies, restarting IP finding proccess.\n".blue.bold
    create_possibles
  end
end
```

So my question is, what am I doing wrong to where the `@ping` won't run properly, and how do I fix it?

Comment: Your code seems a little confused - commented out code, methods that you define but never call etc.

Comment: Oh I totally forgot about the comments, let me edit those out hang on, it's still in the testing phase so I'm trying different ping techniques etc..

Comment: @FrederickCheung Edited out the comments

Comment: As far as I can tell you are only calling ping once ( in the confusingly named check_os method) - not sure why you expect it to be called more than once

Comment: What do you mean? It's suppose to send one packet of data to each IP

Comment: But you never call the method that actually does the pinging

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not actually executing the ping command. At this part:

```
Timeout::timeout(5) do 
    @ping # this isn't doing anything
    if @ping =~ /Received = 1/ 
      puts "[SUCCESS]Possible proxies created for IP: #{@ip}".green.bold
      File.open("proxies.txt", "a+") do |proxy|
        ports.each { |port| proxy.puts("#{@ip}:#{port}") }
      end
    else
      puts "[ERROR]IP failed to ping: #{@ip}".red.bold
    end
  end
```

I assume you expect the line with the `@ping` variable to be executing the command in the shell. You need to do that by using backticks or the system method `system @ping`. This will execute the @ping string in the shell.